# Can quanta have different energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, physical-constants

The energy of a wave is h*f. How i imagine this is each cycle consisting of 1 quanta. I sometimes hear people say the energy of a photon is equal to h*f which makes it sound like each cycle has a higher energy of quanta. which way of thinking is correct?

Comment: What do you mean with cycle? Generally the intensity of an electromagnetic wave is proportional to the photon flux, and the energy of each photon is dependent on the frequency with the formula you mentioned.

Comment: It seems like you're thinking of each wavefront as a photon, when in reality these are wave packets, each of which has a specific energy. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, E is the same as joules, wouldn't this mean that to calculate it you would have to go h*f^2?

Comment: The Planck constant $h$ is in $j.s$ and $f$ in $1/s$, so the units of $hf$ is perfectly fine...

Comment: But if there are more waves per second and each wave has a higher energy how could e=h*f?

Answer (score 1):

> The energy of a wave is h*f.

[The energy in an electromagnetic wave is](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node119.html)

[image]

where E is the electric field of the wave

[image: em wave]

[as it moves](http://www.astronomynotes.com/light/s3.htm) with velocity c.

> How i imagine this is each cycle consisting of 1 quanta.

There are no quanta in the sense you are imagining it. The classical wave above emerges from a zillion of quanta, called photons. For a classical wave of frequency f, the energy of each photon making up the wave is h*f but there are zillions of photons making up the wavefront.

> I sometimes hear people say the energy of a photon is equal to h*f

That is correct. If you have a source of light of frequency f, and lower the intensity to the point of one photon at a time, that photon will have energy h*f, and will show a [wave property in the [**probability**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzbKb59my3U) of its manifestation at a certain x,y of the screen. It is the collection of zillions of photons which will show the classical energy pattern. If you divide the classical energy by h*f you will know how many photons make up the wave front.